# Webmin send fatal error when i try to satart ProFTPD Server

Tags: ssl, webmin, proftpd, virtualmin

I'm trying to start ProFTPD Server but i recieve the next message:

> **Starting proftpd (via systemctl): proftpd.serviceJob for proftpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
>   See "systemctl status proftpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
>    failed!**

And when i get more information about it, i have:

```
fatal: TLSRSACertificateFile. '/etc/ssl/certs/proftp.crt' does not exists on line 8 '/etc/proftpd/conf.d/virtualmin.conf/'
```

I have to say i did'nt installed ProFTPD Server because this module came with the webmin installation.

Hope you can help me to know why `proftp.crt` fie does not exists and how can i fix this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know Webmin (I used it once approximalety 20 years ago..) but there should at least be options to disable TLS for the FTP Server and to change the path to the certificate if it is able to manage ProFTPD for You.

Other alternative (better then turning SSL/TLS off): copy Your cert for the server there (you have to do something similiar for the key I assume), if You do not have one You can get one or create Your own self-signed (not sure whether Webin can help You with that, but on command line it's pretty simple to create one with openssl.)

Answer (score 0):

Come on...

1 - Check if your plugin is active in VirtualMin.

1.1 - Shell check if your SFTP is installed

== ProFTPD install

UBUNTU = apt install proftpd -y

CENTOS = yum install proftpd -y

2 - Check if your domain is SFTP enabled.

3 - Create an SSL within the domain, after created click on the option to use SSL for SFTP.
VIRTUALMIN // Domain >> Server Configuration >> SSL

4 - Create an SSL for the domain you use to access WebMin.
E Use this SSL for WebMin // VirtualMIn

5 - Check the proftpd settings via WEBMIN.

Good luck! Send news about your progress ...